# apcupsd on Linux does not see APC BackUPS Pro 900 on USB

Tags: linux, usb, opensuse, ups

From what documentation I could find, the UPS **is** supported on Linux and is reported to be working with `apcupsd`.

I looked for specific problems such as the infamous Microlink protocol, and found none.

I have found [a feedback from a guy in UK](http://www.ebuyer.com/238120-apc-back-ups-pro-900-ups-ac-230-v-540-watt-900-va-br900gi) that reports using this very model on a not-too-different OS version (his OpenSuSE 12.1, mine 12.3 x86_64).

The USB port is detected, `lsusb` reports it as being used by an APC:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
```

and `lsusb -v -s002:003` confirms and expands:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x051d American Power Conversion
  idProduct          0x0002 Uninterruptible Power Supply
  bcdDevice            0.90
  iManufacturer           1 American Power Conversion
  iProduct                2 Back-UPS RS 900G FW:879.L4 .I USB FW:L4
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    [...]
    Interface Descriptor:
      [...]
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode           33 US
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength    1134
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval             100
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

The kernel recognizes this, and duly sets up a Human Interface Device

```
crw------- 1 root root 180, 96 Nov  4 16:11 /dev/usb/hiddev0
```

So, as far as I know, everything is as it should be.

I have put the standard configuration in `/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf` (which is Unix-terminated, ASCII-only, no BOM (just in case))

```
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE  usb
DEVICE
```

(I have also tried commenting out `DEVICE`, and setting a device of `/dev/puppa` results in an access attempt to `/dev/puppa`, not some `/var/lib/dev/puppa` or `/dev/puppa\r\n`).

Yet, what `apcaccess` tells me is "no UPS here, sorry":

```
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) suse
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2013-11-04 16:24:22 +0100
MODEL    :
STATUS   : NOBATT
LINEV    : 000.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :   0.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 000.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :   0.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Low
LOTRANS  : 000.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 000.0 Volts
```

It doesn't recognize the model, and reports no battery (and no voltage). This confirms that it's not the Microlink problem, or it *would* report the battery status, if precious little else.

If I disconnect the USB cable, I get an `apcupsd` message to the effect that communications have been lost; and I get the "communication restored" broadcast too, if I reconnect the cable. So `apcupsd` *is* monitoring.

So everything tells me that it should work -- *only it doesn't*. Apparently, the UPS won't talk to `apcupsd`. Does anyone spot what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a similar case (re: a different model of UPS, but still USB) that had been solved by the voodoo method of changing the USB port. So I tried. **It worked**.

The output from `lsusb` for the two ports (the one that works, and the one that doesn't) is identical except for this one detail:

```
Device Status:     0x0000           <-- old port
  (Bus Powered)

Device Status:     0x0002           <-- new port
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

I don't know whether this means that the first port lacked 'Remote Wakeup', which for some reasons was required by `apcupsd` (maybe to support [wakeup-on-power-back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37097/can-apc-ups-wake-powered-off-machine-up-when-ac-power-is-back)?), or this port is recognized for some totally different reason, and due to its recognition, a Remote Wakeup gets enabled that previously wasn't.

However, if I put the UPC back to the old port it stops working again, while on the new port I get `apcaccess` reporting, as expected,

```
MODEL    : Back-UPS RS 900G
STATUS   : ONLINE
LINEV    : 231.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  10.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT : 118.4 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Medium
LOTRANS  : 176.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 294.0 Volts
ALARMDEL : 30 seconds
BATTV    : 27.3 Volts
```

Comment: Just for completeness, the first USB port appears to be working okay with both a Webcam, a keyboard, a mouse and a WD external disk. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to set the following variables in apcupsd.conf to get USB to work:

```
UPSCABLE smart
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE
```

Glad that you got it working, but I'm hoping those 3 variables help someone else in the future.  (I'm using CyberPower CP1000AVRLCDa)